# Error capturing number of document copies sent to printer using "Win32_PrintJob" Class

Tags: windows, printing, vbscript, printers, network-printers

Am capturing the data from the documents that are sent to the printer

I use the class "`Win32_PrintJob`". I only need to get the number of copies of each document that was sent to print, for this I use the property '`PagesPrinted`', but when trying to get the number of copies, returns the value "`0`". Looking at the documentation, there is the following explanation: "This value can be `0 (zero)` if the print job does not contain page delimitation information." My question is, what would this "page delimitation" be? How to get the exact number of copies?

Official Documentation: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printjob)

My Code in VBScript:

```
strComputer="."

strPrintQuery="Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'"
Set PRINTSink=WScript.CreateObject("WBemScripting.SWbemSink","PRINTNEW_")
Set objWMI = GetObject("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate, (security)}!\\" & strComputer & "\")
objWMI.ExecNotificationQueryAsync PRINTSink,strPrintQuery

strPrintQuery2="Select * from __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'"
Set PRINTSink2=WScript.CreateObject("WBemScripting.SWbemSink","PRINTDEL_")
Set objWMI2 = GetObject("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate, (security)}!\\" & strComputer & "\")
objWMI2.ExecNotificationQueryAsync PRINTSink2,strPrintQuery2

strPrintQuery3="Select * from __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'"
Set PRINTSink3=WScript.CreateObject("WBemScripting.SWbemSink","PRINTMOD_")
Set objWMI3 = GetObject("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate, (security)}!\\" & strComputer & "\")
objWMI3.ExecNotificationQueryAsync PRINTSink3,strPrintQuery3

strServiceQuery="Select * from __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Service'"
Set SERVICESink=WScript.CreateObject("WBemScripting.SWbemSink","SERVICEMOD_")
Set objWMI4 = GetObject("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate, (security)}!\\" & strComputer & "\")
objWMI4.ExecNotificationQueryAsync SERVICESink,strServiceQuery




While (True) 
     WScript.Sleep (500)
Wend

Sub PRINTNEW_OnObjectReady(objEvent,objContext)
 WriteFile NOW  & "f1 xxx " & objEvent.TargetInstance.PagesPrinted & " xxx " & objEvent.TargetInstance.DriverName & " xxx " & objEvent.TargetInstance.Owner & " xxx " & objEvent.TargetInstance.Name & " xxx " & objEvent.TargetInstance.Document
End Sub



Sub WriteFile(strText)
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objShell, objTextFile, objFile
Dim strDirectory, strFile
strDirectory = "C:
strFile = "\log.txt"

' Create the File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Check that the strDirectory folder exists
If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
   Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
   'WScript.Echo "Just created " & strDirectory
End If

If objFSO.FileExists(strDirectory & strFile) Then
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
   Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
   'Wscript.Echo "Just created " & strDirectory & strFile
End If

set objFile = nothing
on error resume next
set objFolder = nothing
' OpenTextFile Method needs a Const value
' ForAppending = 8 ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
(strDirectory & strFile, ForAppending, True)

' Writes strText every time you run this VBScript
objTextFile.WriteLine(strText)
objTextFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: did you solved this case?